# svg file not displayed in html

Tags: html, svg

The svg file pushpop.svg does not gets diplayed.
The code is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background:black;color:white">

<h1>Primitive operations :-</>
<ol>
<li>Push :- Place the new item on stack.Value of top gets incremented by one.</li>
<li>Pop :- Remove the item from top of the stack.Value of top decreases by one.</li>
</ol>
<img src="pushpop.svg" alt="Kiwi standing on oval">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try closing the h1 tag

Comment: Try giving the `<img>` a width and height.

Comment: @ Sirko still not getting the image displayed..

Comment: Check to make sure that your server is configured to serve svg files as the right type: image/svg+xml

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I would suggest the following two edits.

CLOSE YOUR H1 TAG! as simple as it sounds, leaving tags opened can have knock-on effects

Also you have no doctype, depending on the browser this could also be affecting the svg.

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background:black;color:white">

<h1>Primitive operations :-</h1>
<ol>
    <li>Push :- Place the new item on stack.Value of top gets incremented by one.</li>
    <li>Pop :- Remove the item from top of the stack.Value of top decreases by one.</li>
</ol>
<img src="pushpop.svg" alt="Kiwi standing on oval">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background:black;color:white">

<h1>Primitive operations</h1>
<ol>
<li>Push :- Place the new item on stack.Value of top gets incremented by one.</li>
<li>Pop :- Remove the item from top of the stack.Value of top decreases by one.</li>
</ol>

<embed src="pushpop.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp